# How do I find the length of a decimal number without counting the decimal point?

Tags: python, variables, decimal, digits, string-length

If I have a number 7.14285 and I wanted to find the number of digits in this, how do I do so without the decimal point also being counted as a "digit?"

For example, I did this:

```
n = 7.14285
digits = len(str(n))
print(digits)
```

But it returns "7" to me as the answer.

If I do:

```
n = 714285
digits = len(str(n))
print(digits)
```

Then it returns "6" to me as the answer.

So, how do I count the number of digits in this decimal number and make it equal 6 instead of 7 while keeping n = 7.14285?

Answer (score 3):

`.isdigit` will return `True` if a given character is a digit. `True` also works like the integer `1` so you can sum it

```
sum(d.isdigit() for d in str(n))
```

But be careful! `7.14285` is really a decimal approximation of a binary float. Given greater precision, its closer to `7.1428500000000001435296326235402375459671020507812500`. If this value `n` started out as a string, keep it that way. Otherwise keep in mind that `str(some_float)` gives an approximation of the number.

Comment: Also, beware scientific notation. If `n = 0.00001`, then `sum(d.isdigit() for d in str(n))` is `3`. It's not clear what the "right" answer is, but it's almost certainly not `3`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is just splitting the string using the point and counting the second element of the list that generates.

```
n = 7.14285
digits = str(n).split(".")
print(len(digits[1])) # The Output is 5
```

Comment: seems the correct way, although user says it wants to return 6... so unsure if he wants all digits or just decimals

Answer (score 1):

We just have to remove that '.', Here we have the code to do so:

```
n = 7.14285
digits = len(str(n).replace(".",""))
print(digits)
```

The `.replace(".","")` after `str(n)` will remove the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you need length of floating number, then you can just subtract 1 from the length of given floating number.

```
len(str(n))-1
```